# How to find $R>0$ such that the modulus of $| z^{10}+ 100z + 9|>1$ with $|z|>R$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

> How to find $R>0$ such that the modulus of $| z^{10}+ 100z + 9|>1$ with $|z|>R$?

I don't need to find the best such $R$ but I need to give a reason for choosing a specific $R$. I am not sure how to go about finding this $R$ as using different forms of complex numbers only makes the task more tedious.

Comment: 1. abs(z) admits the triangle inequality, means that $abs(p(z))<=abs(z^10)+abs(10z)+abs(9)$
2. When does $abs(z^10)<abs(z)$?

Answering those 2 questions should help you construct a number and give you reasons.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a go at that. When writing up powers, if your power is more than 1 character you need { }.  z^{10}  and then use the dollar signs

Comment: No success. I seem to miss the point of finding when  $|z|^{10}$<$|z|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG, Let $R>1$ then
\begin{align}
|p(z)|
&= |z^{10}+100z+9| \\
&= |z|^{10}\left|1+\dfrac{100}{z^9}+\dfrac{9}{z^{10}}\right| \\
&\geq |z|^{10}\left(1-\dfrac{100}{|z|^9}-\dfrac{9}{|z|^{10}}\right) \\
&\geq R^{10}\left(1-\dfrac{109}{R}\right)
\end{align}
It is sufficient that $\dfrac{109}{R}<\dfrac12$ or $R>218$ to have $|p(z)|>1$.

Comment: why is it sufficient to say that $\frac{109}{R}$ < $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: You can let $\dfrac{109}{R}<1-\epsilon$ which RH be positive. (need $\epsilon>R^{-10}$. Or make better estimate $R^{10}>R$ then $R^{10}\left(1-\dfrac{109}{R}\right)=R-109>1$ or $R>110$.

Answer (score 0):

By the triangle inequality, $|p(z)| \ge |z^{10}|-|100z+9|$ so if $|z^{10}| \gt |100z+10|$ we are guaranteed that $|p(z)| \gt 1$  We can solve $z^{10}=100z+10$ [in the reals](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E10%3D100z%2B10) to get $z\approx 1.67886$ and that is an $R$ that works.  There may be a slightly smaller one but we have justified this choice.

Comment: You could then add the direct confirmation in that for $|z|\ge R=2$ one gets $|p(z)|\ge |z|^10-100|z|-9\ge 1024-200-9>1$.